# Deploy GAE app with some composer packages outside vendor folder

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, composer-php

I'm trying to install some packages **outside** the `/vendor` folder via the [installer-paths](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) composer directive.

After the deploy those packages aren't installed in the deployment, but the ones in the `vendor` folders are.

There is any way to allow the Cloud build to install composer packages outside `vendor` folder?

I'm deploying a Wordpress website to GAE php72, using a composer based boilerplate [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/).

I've tried to set the those paths to target custom folders inside the /vendor folder and it works, maybe there is some sort of security rules that allows `composer install` only to write into `vendor`?

Here is part of composer.json:

```
{
  // ...
  {
    "composer/installers": "^1.7",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-seo": ">=6.0",
    "wpackagist-theme/twentynineteen":"1.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],    
      "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "web/wp"
  }
  //...
}
```

I've also tried to use composer `post-install-cmd` scripts to copy the packages from `/vendor` folder to the desired location, but the build fails with message:

```
Step #1 - "builder": Script cp vendor/plugins/* web/app/plugins handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
Step #1 - "builder": cp: target 'web/app/plugins' is not a directory
Step #1 - "builder": > cp vendor/plugins/* web/app/plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible since, as Google Cloud Platform [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies) states that composer specifically adds the packages to your app's `vendor/` directory, where **autoload.php** is generated.

Comment: By reading the Cloud Build's output log seem like that only the `/vendor` folder is zipped and uploaded to the image. Sigh. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies#installing_a_web_framework) suggests that GAE is WP compatible. But just wp core, jetpack and woocommerce togheter are easily over 5000 files, and one of our websites, with few more plugins, is over the 10k file limit. Any suggestions to overcome this? I've tried also symlinks but with no luck.

Comment: Hello Brandom! The file upload limit can be increased, however, you would need to contact Google Cloud Platform support in order to make this request.

Comment: I've tried to contact the GCP standard chat support but they can't do anything. Do I need to purchase Silver/Gold Support just to request a quota increase? Do you know any other way to ask this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that deploying with:

`gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache`

installs all packages successfully even outside the `/vendor` folder.